# correctly updating mysql column

Tags: mysql

i have this query  and i am updating mysql column but when there are more than two rows for same shop_id it updates the same data for all rows and i can understand why.

```
   tableA

   ida   shop_id    balance
    1      25       5000
    2      30       8015
    3      32       7550
```

ida is unique but shop_id and balance is not unique

```
   tableB

   id       fquota    used
    25      5000       50
    30      8015      80
    32      7550       75
```

tableB id and tableA shop_id are same

as i am getting the balance value in first

```
SELECT  tableA.shop_id,tableA.ida,tableB.fquota,tableB.used from tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.shop_id=tableB.id  where tableA.delivered='1' order by tableA.ida asc limit 20
```

if this query returns this sort of data then same balance is updated

```
shop_id    ida   fquota   used    
50         151   5000     50
50         152   5000     50
50         153    5000    50
60         154    6000    100
```

so  u can see that shop_id 50 is coming 3 times and everytime the fquota and used is same as we are doing in one query 20 rows so defenitely it will give wrong result for balance and update same value in this case

```
   //  $balanceeeddfkdkd = $fquota - $used - 20;

    //  $balanceeeddfkdkd = 5000-50-20
```

//    same 4930 will be updated in ida 151,152,153

```
 while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($re991))
{



$idaaaa=$row2['ida'];

 $fquota =$row2['fquota'];
 $used =$row2['used'];




 

 $balanceeeddfkdkd = $fquota - $used - 20;

  mysqli_query($con,"update tableA set balance='$balanceeeddfkdkd' where ida='$idaaaa' ");  

 
}
```

everything works as expected problem happens when there are multiple rows for same customer.
in that case same balance is updated for multiple rows, any help will be great.
i want exact balance for each rows and as customer consumes balance will decrease but in our case if 5 rows are coming in that query for one customer, all 5 rows will be updated with same balance and reason is obvious as fquota and used values are taken once when we query to mysql

we tried with this DISTINCT but dont know why it did not work. it should have worked/

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  tableA.shop_id,tableA.ida,tableB.fquota,tableB.used from tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.shop_id=tableB.id  where tableA.delivered='1' order by tableA.ida asc limit 20
```

Comment: it's more helpful when you show us some of your data table in question , for update specific user row why don't you use auto increment value which never repeat .

Comment: Provide tables structure. `c_code` does not exist in query.

Comment: @shubham we are not inserting. auto increment is already there. we are updating column and whereever auto increment is required it is there

Comment: @4EACH we have removed country code.

Comment: in your first select query fetch  **id(auto increment)** and then in update query where condition like   `where ida(userid)='$idaaaa' and id(auto-increment)= '$id'`

Comment: @shubham why u r behind auto increment we are not inserting. we are updating column

Comment: so before updating you are not fetching any value from database?

Comment: What does `ida` column? Does it have unique value ? If not, it will update few records

Comment: @shubham my query is fetching data from database only

Comment: @4EACH ida is unique

Comment: that not possible if ida is unique only one record will be update, please provide your table structure

Comment: Query result does not return 4 records as you mentioned here, I have updated the SQL Fiddle

Comment: Please be warned that the given query is widely open for SQL injection. Better use prepared statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem does not reproduce.

I am trying to reproduce it here:

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87aafc/1)

Insert data that will reproduce your issue.

Comment: hi, i am adding both table in question for clarity

Comment: i have added clear picture of table. request you to read once. you can see rows 151,152 and 153 will update same data